Error: package or namespace load failed ... undefined exports: countrySynonyms
In GitHub package sbgraves237/acledr, I'm getting "undefined exports: countrySynonyms", even though countrySynonyms is in the package, in NAMESPACE, with a *.Rd file that includes both \name{countrySynonyms} and \alias{countrySynonyms}, I can load ~acledr/data/countrySynonyms, AND a function in the package that uses countrySynonyms can find it outside of "R CMD check".
You can see the entire package AND the results of R CMD check of this package on 5 different platforms with GitHub Action at GitHub package sbgraves237/acledr.
This countrySynonyms is a local copy of rworldmap::countrySynonyms, and I got the same "undefined exports" error when I tried to use rworldmap::countrySynonyms. I got around that problem for a while by making this local copy AND deleting my NAMESPACE file. However, with a recent addition, GitHub actions failed, because I didn't have a NAMESPACE file. I recreated NAMESPACE, and this "undefined exports" error came back. (When I started creating this package, I was using Roxygen2. However, Roxygen2 seemed to make it harder for me to diagnose this and other problems, so I ripped it out.)
Suggestions?

I don't think you need to export data using the NAMESPACE. See the packages book. In general, I do recommend using roxygen2 and other tools to make this easier. E.g. usethis::use_data() can be used to set this all up automatically for you.

That was it: I removed "countrySynonyms" from NAMESPACE, and that error message disappeared! Thanks, Spencer Graves
